# Response header does not return Content-Type application/json

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-5

Am trying to change Response header's Content-Type to 'application/json. Tried numerous ways but curl still contains 'text/plain'.

```
  def my_action
    file = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/my_json")
    json = JSON.parse(file)

    # response.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    # response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    # render :text => json, :content_type => 'application/json'
    # render :json => json, :content_type => 'application/json'
    # render json: json, content_type: 'application/json'

    render text: json, content_type: 'application/json'
  end
```

Curl response is

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Nov 2017 14:39:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 181
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.2/2015-04-13)
Date: Thu, 09 Nov 2017 15:04:45 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive`

Rails 5.0.6
Ruby 2.2.2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. The route has the same name as the static file and the static file 'my_json' has priority over route 'my_json'.

```
  get 'my_json', to: 'files#my_action'
```

It resulted in response header as `text/plain` instead of `application/json`.